# Angular 7 is fully reloaded on same URL

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have this code :

```
onSubmit(search: string, from: string, to: string) {
        this.router.navigate(['/recherche'], {
          queryParams: {
            search: search,
            from: from,
            to: to
          }
        });
      }
```

And this view :

```
       <form ngNoForm>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-11">
              <input #search id="search" name="search" class="form-control form-control-lg w-100" type="text" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-1">
              <button (click)="onSubmit(search.value, from.value, to.value);" class="btn btn-lg btn-black" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
            </div>
          </div>
```

This is how I get the parameters on the results page :

```
    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private eventService: EventService,
        private locationService: LocationService,
      ) {});
      }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Subscribe to query parameters
    this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(queryParams => {
      // Retreive the parameters
      let search = queryParams.get('search').trim();
      let from = queryParams.get('from');
      let to = queryParams.get('to');

      // List the events
      this.listEvents(search, from, to);

      // List the locations
      this.listLocations(search);
    });
  }
```

When I first search, everything goes well. If I performed a second search, the app is fully reloaded. What am I missing ?

The routing module code part :

```
{ 
    path: 'recherche',
    component: SearchComponent
  },
```

**To be more precise**, the app is reloaded only when I am on the `/recherche` path. If I move to another router before to perform the second search, it works.

Comment: probably as its an invalid route? it should be `path: 'recherche/:search/:from/:to'`, `:search`, `:from`, `:to` can be anything as long as they start with `:`, its also how you get the data on that page

Comment: @mast3rd3mon : Oh, well, query params cannot just be hidden parameters ? Do they need to be explicitly listed in the path ? I did not understand that reading the documentation...

Comment: using queryparams will create a query-like url, such as `https://www.myweb.com/recherche?search=val1&from=val2&to=val3

Comment: @mast3rd3mon : I added the code you ask for.

Comment: @mast3rd3mon : I use queryParams.... so my code should be working

Comment: you should change the `const`'s to `let`'s if youre only using them in the `ngOnInit`, and you should look into subscribing to route parameters (`this.router.params.subscribe((params) => {console.log(params["search"]);})`)

Comment: @mast3rd3mon : I already use the subscribing, I added it in the question. For the `let`, I will change it.

Comment: never ever use `this.ngOnInit();`... `ngOnInit()` is called by angular and should only be called by angular. dont call it manually

Comment: @mast3rd3mon : Hum how can I reload the view in case of same URL then ? Anyway, regarding my problem, that does not explain the issue..

Comment: I updated my ngOnInit() in the question

Comment: I tried to add `runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'` on the routing module for this particular route, but sill not working. If I am on this view, and I search again, the app is totally reloaded.

Comment: You are not using an angular form, so I guess that is why page reloads when you submit.

Comment: @AJT_82 : It does not reload when I am on any other route than `/recherche`. It only reload on the route `/recherche`. So I think the `noNgForm` is not the issue..

Comment: So what does the form and routing has to do with your issue, if it only happens on the `/recherche` route?

Comment: If the issue with reloading has to do with the form submit, that would be the issue of the reload, as the default form action is added, which if you do not provide the action, the page reloads, that is expected. But if the form has nothing to do with it, I don't understand why you are showing it?

Comment: @AJT_82 : The form is in fact a component called `search-bar.component` and it is displayed on every view, in the header, see ? So, wherever you are, you can start a search. The results are displayed in a dedicated component (and view) called `search.component` (the `/recherche` route). When you are in the results page, you can also perform a new search, but in that case, you already are in the `/recherche` view. You see ?

Comment: @AJT_82 : I tried with a Reactive From and it is working, you were right ! Thanks !

Comment: Great, glad to hear your issue got sorted out! :)